# Passing data from child to parent in React shows type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React Js

I am trying to pass value from child to parent and while showing components through a map there shows an error in the emit/trigger function

```
render(){
            var choices =['krass', 'Einfach', 'Dazu', 'Dafur'];
            const listitem = choices.map(function(name, index){
                <Choice onIncreaseCount={this.increaseCount}  key={index} option={name} /> ;
            });

            return (
                    <div className="col-md-12 row">
                        {listitem}
                    </div>
            );
        }
```

Below error message is shown

```
react-dom.development.js:10289 The above error occurred in the <Choices> component:
    in Choices (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
 boundaries.
logCapturedError    @   react-dom.development.js:10289
captureError    @   react-dom.development.js:11082
renderRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:10933
performWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:11556
performWork @   react-dom.development.js:11509
requestWork @   react-dom.development.js:11420
scheduleWorkImpl    @   react-dom.development.js:11274
scheduleWork    @   react-dom.development.js:11231
scheduleTopLevelUpdate  @   react-dom.development.js:11735
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:11773
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:15900
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:11644
renderSubtreeIntoContainer  @   react-dom.development.js:15899
render  @   react-dom.development.js:15964
(anonymous) @   Inline Babel script:141
n   @   babel.min.js:12
r   @   babel.min.js:12
o   @   babel.min.js:12
u   @   babel.min.js:12
E   @   babel.min.js:1
```

codepen link is https://codepen.io/jahid93/pen/VypwjO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `.map`.

Change it to this:

```
const listitem = choices.map((name, index) => {
      return(<Choice onIncreaseCount={this.increaseCount} key={index} option={name} />);
```

**Note** that i changed the anonymous function of `map` to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to handle the context of `this` in a lexical way.

Running code from your code-pen link:

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <p className="title-p">
          <span className="red-text">B</span>
          <span className="black-text">ulows</span>{" "}
          <span className="green-text">Wortshatztest</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Hicon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 icon-image-div">
        <img className="icon-image" src="src/img/WT_icon5.png" alt="icon" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Question extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h3 className="question-type">Welche beiden Worter passen gut zu:</h3>
        <h1 className="question">Gegensatz</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Instruction extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <h4 className="attention-text">
          Wählen Sie Ihre zwei. [attention German Umlaut = auml]
        </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Choice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true, selectCount: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    console.log(this.state.isToggleOn);
    this.props.onIncreaseCount();
  }

  render() {
    let bgColor = this.state.isToggleOn ? "white" : "green";
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 text-center btn-div">
        <a
          style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          type="button"
          className="btn"
          href="#"
        >
          {this.props.option}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Choices extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      choices: [
        { option: "Krass" },
        { option: "Einfach" },
        { option: "Dazu" },
        { option: "Dafur" }
      ]
    };
    this.increaseCount = this.increaseCount.bind(this);
  }

  increaseCount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    if (this.state.count == 2) {
      console.log("kam sarse");
    }
  }

  render() {
    var choices = ["krass", "Einfach", "Dazu", "Dafur"];
    const listitem = choices.map((name, index) => {
      return(<Choice onIncreaseCount={this.increaseCount} key={index} option={name} />);
    });

    return (
      <div className="col-md-12 row">
        <Choice onIncreaseCount={this.increaseCount} option="Krass" />
        {listitem}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row header">
          <Header />
          <Hicon />
        </div>
        <div className="row question-div">
          <Question />
        </div>
        <div className="row instruction-div">
          <Instruction />
        </div>
        <div className="row choice-div">
          <Choices />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.header{
      border-bottom: 5px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .title-p{
      padding-bottom: 0px !important;
      margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
    .red-text{
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }
    .black-text{
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .green-text{
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: green;
    }
    .icon-image{
      height: 50px;
      float: right;
    }
    .icon-image-div{
      padding-top: 25px;
    }
    .question-div{
      background-color: aliceblue;
      min-height: 20%;
    }
    .instruction-div{
      background-color: goldenrod;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .choice-div{
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .zero-padding{
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
    .btn-div{
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .btn{
      width: 80%;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: black;
    }
    .btn:hover{
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    .btn:focus{
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;
      /*background-color: green;*/
      /*color: white;*/
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Error is saying this.increaseCount uncaught type error
I think it is not involved with return
Have a look at codepen

Comment: @Md.JahidulIslam i've added a running example with your code to the answer. note that i used an arrow function to handle the context of `this`

Answer (score 0):

You dont got the return statement in your map function.. please add return and it will work